# Manhua with royal pink-haired female lead set in ancient China

Tags: story-identification, manga

I have been searching for this Manhua since a pretty long time but just can't find it.

It's about a pink-haired female lead and I think she was an Empress or at least a princess. (It is set in ancient China I think.) She had some kind of mark on her forehead, I think.  She got married to her black-haired childhood friend who treats her pretty badly!

She meets a blue-haired knight who has his hair up in some kind of ponytails and falls in love with him.  The black-haired guy dies during a fire while protecting female lead.

In the end the female lead doesn't end up with anyone because she can't get over the black-haired guy and rejects the blue-haired knight.

Does anyone know which Manhua I am searching for?  It had a really pretty art style!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When and where did you read this?

Comment: I'm not seeing any sci fi or fantasy content here